# Using Powershell I want to Forcefully Copy Folder/files Without Erasing Extra Files in Existing Destination Folder:

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell and am trying to forcefully copy folder/files without erasing any extra files in existing destination folders. I am stuck trying to get a working command.

Below is my code, any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
Copy-Item -Force -Recurse  –Verbose $releaseDirectory -Destination $sitePath
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to be sure that

```
$realeseDirectory
```

is something like

```
c:\releasedirectory\*
```

`Copy-item` never delete extra files or folders in destination, but with `-force` it will owerwrite if file already exists

Comment: Hello C.B. $releaseDirectory = $BuildFilePath + $ProjectName + "\" + $ProjectName + "\bin\" + $compileMode + "\_PublishedWebsites\" + $ProjectName     $sitePath = "\\$strSvr\c$\Shared\WebSites"  currently it is deleting extra file on the destination.

Comment: @user2062422 I cannot say if paths are builded correctly but for copy all files from the source you need to add `\*` at the end of the source path.. It's really strange the behaviour... make a test in local with some test path... and you will see no extra file deleted..

Comment: Hello C.B. - Path is correct. Currently source has c:\test\file 1,file2 and Destination has c:\shared\website\file1, file2 and file3. It should overwrite file1 and file2 and should keep file3. It is overwriting file1,file2 and deleting file3

Comment: @user2062422 um.. Never had this behaviour.. have you done the test I told before?

Comment: Yes. Releasedirectory has now \\* with the path.

Comment: Are you sure that file3 does not exist in source and isn't an hidden file? In this case, it will be hidden in the remote share, but is just an remote hypothesis

Comment: file3 does not exist in source and is not hidden file. Before I copy source file3 exist in destination. After copy file3 does not exist.

Comment: @user2062422 I clearly understood your issue, but I never had it. I can't help you.

Comment: @userC.B. No problem. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @userC.B I had a command before copy-item (Remove-Item), which was removing the file3. I have fix the command and now everything is working. So your trick of c:\releasedirectory\* has helped me.

Comment: @user2062422 Glad to help! For the future comments: is just (at)C.B. withour user ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. So, you might have to tweak the function below a bit. By the way, if you are attempting to deploy a web site, copying a directory isn't the best way.

```
function Copy-Directory
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $source,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $destination        
    )

    try
    {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer } |
            ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination } |
            ForEach-Object { $null = New-Item -ItemType Container -Path $_ }

        Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
            Where-Object { -not $_.psIsContainer } |
            Copy-Item -Force -Destination { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination }
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Error "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }
}

$releaseDirectory = $BuildFilePath + $ProjectName + "\" + $ProjectName + "\bin\" + $compileMode + "_PublishedWebsites\" + $ProjectName
$sitePath = "\\$strSvr\c$\Shared\WebSites" 

Copy-Directory $releaseDirectory $sitePath
```

Comment: Currently source has c:\test\file 1,file2 and Destination has c:\shared\website\file1, file2 and file3. It should overwrite file1 and file2 and should keep file3. It is overwriting file1,file2 and deleting file3