# How to copy content of a folder to another specific folder using powershell?

Tags: powershell

`a`, `b`, and `c` are files in a folder `~\Source\x\`, and `b`, `d`, and `f` are files in a folder `~\Destination\x\`. I want files `a` and `c` to be copied to `~\Destination\x\`, and for `~\Destination\x\b` to be replaced with `~\Source\x\b`.

`~\Destination\x\` should have `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `f`.

Comment: yeah i was able to copy from one folder to other, but was unable to replace the files

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) with [Force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819205/using-powershell-i-want-to-forcefully-copy-folder-files-without-erasing-extra-fi) looks like what you are looking for.

```
[string]$sourceDirectory  = "C:\Source\*"
[string]$destinationDirectory = "C:\Destination\"
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory
```

> Copy-item never delete extra files or folders in destination, but with
> `-force` it will overwrite if file already exists

Comment: Hi Eric, its not overwriting, i have a "Me.txt" file(containg text 'overwritten') in a Sub-Folder(A1)in folder(Source) .also, a "Me.txt" file(containg text 'overwrite me') in a Sub-Folder(A1)in folder(Destination)..

Comment: @Deepak Try my code again. I fixed up a couple of mistakes I had before.

Comment: +1. I don't know if it will help anyone but if you're embedding a PS script in Octopus Deploy and using OD variables within this code (or any PS code with string operations), the OD variables has to be wrapped with the double quotes otherwise OD's PS doesn't compile it as a string i.e [string]$sourceDirectory  = "#{MyODVariable}*"